# Correct way to put PHP inside HTML equal to PHP variable?

Tags: php, html, variables

What would be the correct way to put a PHP variable inside HTML that is equal to a PHP variable?  Sorry if that's a bit confusing, here's what I mean:

```
$v = '<center><embed width="420" height="236" src="<?= $pcv ?>" type="application/x-shockwave-flash"></embed></center><hr>';
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The simplest way would be to use [**concatenation**](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php).

```
 $v = '<center><embed width="420" height="236" src="'.$pcv.'" type="application/x-shockwave-flash"></embed></center><hr>';
```

Answer (score 2):

John's answer is my favourite, but an alternative:

```
<center>
   <embed width="420" height="236" src="<?php echo $pcv; ?>" type="application/x-shockwave-flash">
   </embed>
</center>
<hr/>
```